# Selenium を使って Firefox を起動したい

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**現象**
VSCodeで開いたJupyter Notebookで下記のPythonのコードを実行すると、エラーが表示されてFirefoxが起動できません。

```
from selenium import geckodriver

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3513/2951967038.py in <module>
----> 1 from selenium import geckodriver

ImportError: cannot import name 'geckodriver' from 'selenium' (/home/yusuke/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/__init__.py)

from time import sleep
browser = geckodriver.Firefox()
```

**期待値**
Firefoxを起動したいです。

**再現手順**

1. Ubuntuのホームディレクトリにanacondaをインストールする。
2. VSCodeをインストールする。
3. VSCodeにPythonの拡張機能とJupyter Notebookの拡張機能をインストールする。
4. Jupyter Notebookのカーネルを`~/anaconda3/envs/dev/bin/python`に設定する。
5. Jupyter Notebookで`!conda install geckodriver`を実行し、geckodriverのPATHを通すためのShell Scriptを、.bashrcに追記する。
6. 「現象」にあるPythonのコードを実行する。

**再現手順（追記）**
7. geckodriverをアンインストールする。
8. Linux版Google Chromeのバージョン99をインストールする。
9. ChromeDriverのバージョン99をインストールする。
10. VSCodeで開いたJupyter Notebookで下記のPythonのコードを実行する。
コードの下にエラーも追記してます。

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     71             cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
---> 72             self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
     73                                             close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',

~/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask)
    950 
--> 951             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    952                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,

~/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, gid, gids, uid, umask, start_new_session)
   1820                         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1821                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1822                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3513/4270241205.py in <module>
----> 1 browser = webdriver.Firefox()

~/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py in __init__(self, firefox_profile, firefox_binary, timeout, capabilities, proxy, executable_path, options, service_log_path, firefox_options, service_args, desired_capabilities, log_path, keep_alive)
    162                 service_args=service_args,
    163                 log_path=service_log_path)
--> 164             self.service.start()
    165 
    166             capabilities.update(options.to_capabilities())

~/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     79         except OSError as err:
     80             if err.errno == errno.ENOENT:
---> 81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
     83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)

WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: geckodriverのあるフォルダをPATHに加えてexportしていないか、スクリプトの中で明示的に指定していないのでは？ [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40208051/9014308), ["ubuntu install geckodriver" Code Answer's](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/ubuntu+install+geckodriver)

Comment: コードを実行すると現状ではどのような結果になるのかを質問に追記してください。

Comment: エラーメッセージのとおり、`geckodriver`というモジュールは`selenium`からは`import`出来ないのでは？ 先にコメントで紹介したものやこの辺の記事で`import`しているのは全て`webdriver`ですよ。[Cant run Selenium on Ubuntu with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62440799/9014308), [geckodriver not opening firefox on ubuntu using selenium with django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62843069/9014308), [How to properly use selenium with geckodriver and firefox with python on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57870311/9014308)

Comment: @kunif `chromedriver`をインストールした上で、`webdriver`を`import`しても、ブラウザが立ち上がりませんでした。

Comment: その時にエラーメッセージとか何かおかしな現象が発生していませんでしたか？ それらの詳細を追記してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

**解決手順**

1. `geckodriver`を`/usr/local/bin/`にインストール。
2. `~/.bashrc`に`geckodriver`のPATHを通す設定を記述する。以下のように記述する。

```
PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

3. `chromedriver` を`/usr/local/bin/`にインストール。
4. `~/.bashrc`に`chromedriver`のPATHを通す設定を記述する。以下のように記述する。

```
PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

5. 下記のコードを実行する。
   「現象」に記述したPythonのコードの`geckodriver`を`webdriver`に書き換えること！

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```